# python surface plot from 3 1D arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, mayavi

I have 3 one dimensional arrays. Each array consists of floating point numbers. The first array represents x axis coordinates. The second y, the third z. If you put corresponding points from each array into an ordered triple you have a point in xyz space. These arrays are read in from a file. In this application the z is actually a thickness. What is the best way to create a surface plot in these circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to start mayavi in interactive more in ipython by importing mlab and then use its surf function:

```
import mlab
mlab.surf(x,y,z)
```

Hope this helps.